# Приложение как сервис автозаполнения

Tags: android, flutter

Пробовал [flutter_autofill_service](https://github.com/kee-org/flutter_autofill_service), [authpass/autofill_service](https://github.com/authpass/autofill_service)
Но ничего не получается.
В первом варианте не понятно как запускается autofillEntryPoint рядом с main.
Во втором не совместим с flutter_secure_storage (API Версии).
Build Log с API версией меньше 32: [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/fU2Z0pTL)
С 32 Версией: https://pastebin.com/jvym7M99

В гугле никакой информации по реализации. Только "как показать сервису автозаполнения, какие данные нужны в TextField" (как пример).

Как это реализовывается?